# Phantomjs loads different page than chrome

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, screen-scraping

I am trying to download the html from the following link:

http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/TRLH3/1000430019?gameHash=a5e39c76a8e91ba9&tab=stats

When I open in chrome it loads the match with all of the data I want to download into an html. I want to open these pages in phantomjs, but they do not load the same? I am using the following code to take a screenshot of what phantomjs loads. which is just the main match history page: http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url="http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/TRLH3/1000430019?gameHash=a5e39c76a8e91ba9&tab=stats";
console.log('The default user agent is ' + page.settings.userAgent);
page.settings.userAgent = 'SpecialAgent';

page.open(url, function(status) {

  if (status !== 'success') {
     console.log('Unable to access network');
  }

 setTimeout(function (){page.render('mh.png');},1000);
 setTimeout(function (){phantom.exit();},1200);
  });
```

I am not sure why they render two different things. How can I get pahntomjs to render the same thing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @andrew-lohr has noted, this is happening because PhantomJS drops the fragment when processing a redirect. There was an issue lodged (https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12192) and pull request created to fix (https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/pull/14941) but these haven't made their way into release as PhantomJS has suspended development (https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/15344).

An alternative is to use Puppeteer (https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) which has a usage example as to how to capture a screenshot.

In your case, this could be as simple as installing Puppeteer:

```
npm install puppeteer
```

then updating your code to:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/TRLH3/1000430019?gameHash=a5e39c76a8e91ba9&tab=stats');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'mh.png'});
  await browser.close();
})();
```

and running the code via `node` instead of `phantomjs`:

```
node <filename>.js
```

The Puppeteer site has more information on what can be configured (view port etc).

Comment: @KRam no problem. Iif that helps you, you can mark this as answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `http` link is probably getting redirected to `https`. My guess is that phantom.js is not preserving the fragment identifier (the `#match-details`)  or anything after it on the redirect, which is why you are getting the main page `http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en`

To fix your issue, use the link with `https` and that will work since you will not get redirected.

```
var url="https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/TRLH3/1000430019?gameHash=a5e39c76a8e91ba9&tab=stats";
```